# JavaFX: Program terminates without running upon trying to add images

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to add an image using ImageView in JavaFX. My code was running completely fine before attempting to add images, now it doesn't display errors but terminates before running for no reason. I'm using Eclipse and I've installed all the Web Design packages just in case that's why and it hasn't helped.

Here is my code, only the top bit where the images are added is important:

```
public class MainGUI extends Application{

    Button btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8, btn9, btn10;
    Text info1, error1, error2, error3, error4, error5, form1, form2, form3, form4, form5, form6, form7, form8, form9, form10;
    Label lbl1, lbl2, lbl3, lbl4, lbl5;
    TextField input1, input2, input3, input4, input5, input6, input7, input8, input9, input10;
    GridPane pane1, pane2, pane3, pane4, pane5;
    Scene scene1, scene2, scene3, scene4, scene5;
    ImageView imgView1;
    Image img1;
    Stage stage;

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        stage = primaryStage;
        imgView1 = new ImageView();//this terminates my code
        img1 = new Image(MainGUI.class.getResourceAsStream("src/add_medication_button.png"));//this terminates my code
        imgView1.setImage(img1);//this terminates my code
        btn1 = new Button("Add Existing Medication");
        btn2 = new Button("Add New Medication");
        btn3 = new Button("Submit Medication");
        btn4 = new Button("Submit Medication");
        btn5 = new Button("Back");
        btn6 = new Button("Back");
        btn7 = new Button("Back");
        btn8 = new Button("Current Medication Details");
        btn9 = new Button("Quit");
        btn10 = new Button("Back");
        info1 = new Text(getMedName());
        form1 = new Text("Pharmaceutical Company: ");
        form2 = new Text("Medication: ");
        form3 = new Text("Strength (mg): ");
        form4 = new Text("Barcode: ");
        form5 = new Text("No. Tablets per Package: ");
        form6 = new Text("Pharmaceutical Company: ");
        form7 = new Text("Medication: ");
        form8 = new Text("Strength (mg): ");
        form9 = new Text("Barcode: ");
        form10 = new Text("No. Tablets per Package: ");
        error1 = new Text();
        error2 = new Text();
        error3 = new Text();
        error4 = new Text();
        error5 = new Text();
        input1 = new TextField();
        input2 = new TextField();
        input3 = new TextField();
        input4 = new TextField();
        input5 = new TextField();
        input6 = new TextField();
        input7 = new TextField();
        input8 = new TextField();
        input9 = new TextField();
        input10 = new TextField();

        btn1.setOnAction(e -> ButtonClicked(e));
        btn2.setOnAction(e -> ButtonClicked(e));
        btn3.setOnAction(e -> ButtonClicked(e));
        btn4.setOnAction(e -> ButtonClicked(e));
        btn5.setOnAction(e -> ButtonClicked(e));
        btn6.setOnAction(e -> ButtonClicked(e));
        btn7.setOnAction(e -> ButtonClicked(e));
        btn8.setOnAction(e -> ButtonClicked(e));
        btn9.setOnAction(e -> ButtonClicked(e));
        btn10.setOnAction(e -> ButtonClicked(e));
        lbl1 = new Label("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~PMA Main Page~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
        lbl2 = new Label("~~~~~~~~~~Add Existing Medication~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
        lbl3 = new Label("~~~~~~~~~~~~Add New Medication~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
        lbl4 = new Label("~~~~~~~~~~~~Medication Details~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
        lbl5 = new Label("~~~~~~~~~~Traffic Light Evaluation~~~~~~~~~~~~");

        pane1 = new GridPane();
        pane2 = new GridPane();
        pane3 = new GridPane();
        pane4 = new GridPane();
        pane1.setVgap(10);
        pane2.setVgap(10);
        pane3.setVgap(10);
        pane4.setVgap(10);
        pane1.add(lbl1, 0, 0, 2, 1);
        pane1.add(info1, 1, 1, 1, 4);
        pane1.add(btn1, 0, 1);
        pane1.add(btn2, 0, 2);
        pane1.add(btn8, 0, 3);
        pane1.add(btn9, 0, 4);
        pane2.add(lbl2, 0, 0, 2, 1);
        pane2.add(form1, 0, 1);
        pane2.add(form2, 0, 2);
        pane2.add(form3, 0, 3);
        pane2.add(form4, 0, 4);
        pane2.add(form5, 0, 5);
        pane2.add(input1, 1, 1);
        pane2.add(input2, 1, 2);
        pane2.add(input3, 1, 3);
        pane2.add(input4, 1, 4);
        pane2.add(input5, 1, 5);
        pane2.add(btn3, 1, 6);
        pane2.add(btn5, 0, 6);
        pane3.add(lbl3, 0, 0, 2, 1);
        pane3.add(form6, 0, 1);
        pane3.add(form7, 0, 2);
        pane3.add(form8, 0, 3);
        pane3.add(form9, 0, 4);
        pane3.add(form10, 0, 5);
        pane3.add(input6, 1, 1);
        pane3.add(input7, 1, 2);
        pane3.add(input8, 1, 3);
        pane3.add(input9, 1, 4);
        pane3.add(input10, 1, 5);
        pane3.add(btn4, 1, 6);
        pane3.add(btn6, 0, 6);
        pane4.add(lbl4, 0, 0, 2, 1);
        pane4.add(btn10, 0, 2);

        scene1 = new Scene(pane1, 500, 400);
        scene2 = new Scene(pane2, 500, 400);
        scene3 = new Scene(pane3, 500, 400);
        scene4 = new Scene(pane4, 500, 400);
        primaryStage.setTitle("PMA System");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void ButtonClicked(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getSource()==btn1)
            stage.setScene(scene2);
        else if(e.getSource()==btn2)
            stage.setScene(scene3);
        else if(e.getSource()==btn3) {
            String newString = getFormData();
            addToMedication(newString);
            String newMeds = getMedName();
            System.out.println(newMeds);
            info1.setText("");
            info1 = new Text(getMedName());
            pane1.add(info1, 1, 1, 1, 4);
            input1.setText("");
            input2.setText("");
            input3.setText("");
            input4.setText("");
            input5.setText("");
            stage.setScene(scene1);
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==btn4) {
            String newString = getFormData();
            addToMedication(newString);
            String newMeds = getMedName();
            System.out.println(newMeds);
            info1.setText("");
            info1 = new Text(clearMedDetails());
            pane1.add(info1, 1, 1, 1, 4);
            stage.setScene(scene1);

        }
        else if(e.getSource()==btn5) {
            input1.setText("");
            input2.setText("");
            input3.setText("");
            input4.setText("");
            input5.setText("");
            stage.setScene(scene1);
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==btn6) {
            input6.setText("");
            input7.setText("");
            input8.setText("");
            input9.setText("");
            input10.setText("");
            stage.setScene(scene1);
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==btn7)
            stage.setScene(scene1); 
        else if(e.getSource()==btn8) {
            createTable();
            stage.setScene(scene4);
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==btn9)
            System.exit(0);
        else if(e.getSource()==btn10) {
            stage.setScene(scene1);
        }
        else
            stage.setScene(scene1);
    }

    public String getFormData() {
        String pharmComp = input1.getText();
        String medication = input2.getText();
        String strength = input3.getText();
        String barCode = input4.getText();
        String tablets = input5.getText();
        int barCodeLength = barCode.length();

        try {
            float strengthFloat = Float.parseFloat(strength);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Strength field should be a float not string.");     
        }
        try {
            int barCodeInt = Integer.parseInt(barCode);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Barcode field should be an integer not string.");
        }
        try {
            int tabletsInt = Integer.parseInt(tablets);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Tablets should be an integer not string.");
        }
        if(barCodeLength == 13){

        } else {
            System.err.println("Barcode must be 13 digits long.");
        }
        String newMedString = "";
        newMedString = newMedString + pharmComp + "," + medication + "," + strength + "," + barCode + "," + tablets;
        System.out.println(newMedString);
        return newMedString;
    }

    public String getMedName() {
        String filename = "userMed.txt";
        String currentmed = "";

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
            String currentline;

            while ((currentline = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] arrayline = currentline.split(",");
                String toprint = arrayline[1];
                System.out.println(toprint);
                currentmed = currentmed + toprint + "\n";
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return currentmed;/*this should just return names of medication*/
    }

    public String clearMedDetails() {
        return "";
    }

    public void addToMedication(String addThis) {
        BufferedWriter bw = null;

        try {
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("userMed.txt",true));
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write(addThis);
            bw.flush();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if (bw != null) try {
                bw.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        populateTable(addThis);
    }

    public void createTable() {
        TableView<Medication> table = new TableView<Medication>();

        // Create column UserName (Data type of String).
        TableColumn<Medication, String> pharmCompCol //
                = new TableColumn<Medication, String>("Pharmaceutical Company");

        // Create column Email (Data type of String).
        TableColumn<Medication, String> medicationCol//
                = new TableColumn<Medication, String>("Medication");

        // Create column FullName (Data type of String).
        TableColumn<Medication, String> strengthMgCol//
                = new TableColumn<Medication, String>("Strength (mg)");

        // Create 2 sub column for FullName.
        TableColumn<Medication, String> barCodeCol//
                = new TableColumn<Medication, String>("Barcode");

        TableColumn<Medication, String> noTabletsCol //
                = new TableColumn<Medication, String>("No. of Tablets");

        // Defines how to fill data for each cell.
        // Get value from property of UserAccount. .
        pharmCompCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("pharmComp"));
        medicationCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("medication"));
        strengthMgCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("strengthMg"));
        barCodeCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("barCode"));
        noTabletsCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("noTablets"));

        // Display row data
        ObservableList<Medication> list = populateTable("");
        table.setItems(list);
        table.getColumns().addAll(pharmCompCol, medicationCol, strengthMgCol, barCodeCol, noTabletsCol);
        pane4.add(table, 0, 1);
    }

    public ObservableList<Medication> populateTable(String newRow) {
        String filename = "userMed.txt";
        String currentmed = "";

        ObservableList<Medication> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        if(newRow != "") {
            String[] newline = newRow.split(",");
            Medication newUser = new Medication(newline[0],newline[1],newline[2],newline[3],newline[4]);
            list.add(newUser);
        }
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
            String currentline;

            while ((currentline = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] arrayline = currentline.split(",");
                Medication user = new Medication(arrayline[0],arrayline[1],arrayline[2],arrayline[3],arrayline[4]);
                list.add(user);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return list;

}
```

}

Comment: Please create a [MCVE]. Right now you have 300+ lines of code that are not even complete. Get rid of all the code that's not relevant to your question and use an open source image, so others can copy your code and execute it. Note that it is extremely unlikely that path to the image is correct (the `src` folder is not likely to be accessible at runtime), so you should double-check there are no exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you access in-package resources you don't include `src` but start with a `/` for example using different folder structures:

```
Eclipse Project
  |__ src/
        |___ com/
        |     |___ image1.png
        |     |___ stackoverflow/
        |             |___ image2.png
        |             |___ MainGUI.java
        |___ image3.png
```

In your JavaFX application you would access resources like the following:

```
Image image1 = new Image(MainGUI.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/image1.png"));
Image image2 = new Image(MainGUI.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/stackoverflow/image2.png"));
Image image3 = new Image(MainGUI.class.getResourceAsStream("/image3.png"));

// So in your case, you would change your line to this:
img1 = new Image(MainGUI.class.getResourceAsStream("/add_medication_button.png"));
```

Comment: Note though that the OP states that there are no exceptions. If the path were wrong, there would be an exception...

Comment: He does mention in the code `//this terminates my code` which I assumed meant exception.